# Is there a faster way to draw without using Pane.getChildren().removeAll()?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, view, rectangles

The code below is very slow, especially if there are alot of rectangles. I am looking for a **faster way to draw these rectangles.** I can store the total amount of rectangles in an Arraylist and use `.setTranslateX();` to move the rectangles. and use `.setVisible(false)` to only show the rectangles in the screen. But **I think drawing all rectangles would be even slower**.

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
AnchorPane background;


private void updateMap() {
    background.getChildren().removeAll(rectangles);
    rectangles.clear();
    for (int y=0;y<map.getTiles().size(); y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<map.getTiles().get(y).size(); x++) {
            if (isRectInScreen(x, y , tileSize)) {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x*tileSize+map.getBackPosX(), y*tileSize+map.getBackPosY(), tileSize,tileSize);
                r.setFill(new Color(0,0,0,1));
                rectangles.add(r);
            }
        }
    }
    background.getChildren().addAll(rectangles);
}
```

Comment: It depends what you're doing, and how many rectangles there are. If you want the rectangles to be interactive (i.e. you're going to register event handlers with each of them) then what you've described is probably your best approach. If you're just rendering something visual, then consider a [`Canvas`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) or even [`WritableImage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html).

Comment: don't assume, instead profile to find performance bottlenecks :)